# CSS Transform causes rendering errors with FancyBox 3 on Safari

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I'm using FancyBox 3.

The page uses CSS transform to create a 3D hover and a "card flip" animation.

```
-webkit-transform   :   rotateY(180deg);
        transform   :   rotateY(180deg);

-webkit-transform   :   rotateY(15deg);
        transform   :   rotateY(15deg);
```

However, on Safari (and mobile Safari) the CSS transforms cause rendering issues with FancyBox 3.

At appears as if everything with the transform property applied is partially or fully above the lightbox.

(See [this image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkJBj.png), [another image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC9c7.jpg), as well as [a live version here.](https://eightpointdesign.com/testing/IFIC/index.html))

When I remove the transform property, the issue goes away.

Chrome and Firefox don't have a problem and the lightbox works as expected.

Any ideas what's causing this and what the solution is?

Edit: I should mention, there are two transform effects on this page.

The first is a 15° only on hover.

The second is the 180° on click.

Either one causes the same problems.

Comment: Well, as far as I can see it is not working well on either Chrome nor Mozilla if I use the rotate 180, on the live version you have it set to 15. When you hover over the box it flickers, because the div is spinning and the hover loses it's target so a solution on that matter would be to use the :hover on the same-height class or insert another div beneath  instead of using it on the card.

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu I made an edit to my post. The 15° is only for the hover state. On click, the 180° transform is applied.

Comment: Now the link shows a different content

Comment: I could not find out how to trigger fancybox on your page. Also, you have JS error in your code.

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu I’ve updated the url

Comment: @Janis I’ve updated the url. You have to click on “meet a food nerd”

Answer (score 0):

Remove the :hover effect for devices smaller than 996px(so make a media screen and use `min-width:996px;`), you don't need it on tablet or phone which do not use mouse yo hover over stuff.

Secondly, at `max-width:995px;` media screen, remove the Resources and the 2 links you have on the back of the cards, it is too much information, and reduce the `font-size` and `line-height`, making it responsive.

Comment: Thanks. But I’m not sure if this is related to the problem with safari? I can see that this could resolve a part of the problem on mobile safari but I’m still not sure what that does for the weird rendering issue on regular safari.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find out how to fix this Safari issue, maybe try to do differently - disable all transitions while fancybox is active, something like this (not tested; you might need to adjust to work for you):

```
body.fancybox-active .card * {
    transition: none !important;
}
```